# PHP cron job vs. access through web browser

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script that is parsing an RSS feed and entering the info in a db. I am using PHP5.

It is a .php page, and works like a charm when accessed through the web server & browser. (http://myhost.com/rssjob.php)

Now i want to set it up as a CRON job - however when i execute it through SSH/CRON job - it throws exceptions like " Invalid argument supplied for foreach() " in following code.

Question:
1. Why is there a delta in the results i get through accessing the PHP page throw the browser and when i try to execute it as a CRON job/SSH command line?? Is there something more i should specify for the php page to work well when accessed through SSH/commandline/cron job?

$xml = parseRSS("http://www.myhost.com/rss/");

```
//SAMPLE USAGE OF 
foreach($xml['RSS']['CHANNEL']['ITEM'] as $item) {
        //echo("<p>");
    $title = $item['TITLE'];

    $description = $item['DESCRIPTION'];
```

Comment: Without more than invalid arguement supplied, it's hard to know what's happening.  Might be useful to remember though that it's likely not the same php.ini being read as the one that Apache loads.  Could be something in php.ini blocking the http://.../ request or something like that.  Are you getting any other errors?

Comment: Why don't you show us print_r($xml)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution (hack) is to call your script via HTTP from cron:

```
? * * * * curl http://PATH.TO.YOUR/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of differences in running a script through cron vs web. For example, cron will not have a $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable.
If you are using that in your script, this will probably break it.

I'm not sure what happens before your sample lines, but for some reason, $xml is not the array that you expect it to be and like it appears in the web version.
Please check what value the $xml variable has when running it from cron.
An easy way to determine if the script is running from command-line / cron is:

```
$cron = (bool) defined('STDIN');
```

Comment: I would probably do PHP_SAPI === 'cli' instead of checking if STDIN is defined.